# android.process.acore force-closing due to contacts list crashing

Tags: contacts, system-freeze, force-close, samsung-galaxy-s-advance

I've installed Android 4.1.2 on the Samsung Galaxy S Advance. I cope with a problem that more Android users have to deal with. The well-known `android.process.acore` force-closing (FC) or something similar. The constantly appearing FC notifications would be caused by your crashing contact list. However, I cannot find a solution for this anywhere while many users have this problem. It is really annoying when you have to open WhatsApp 3 times because the whole system freezes.

I've tried the options they give in [force-close tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/force-close/info),
but rebooting and resetting obviously wouldn't help, and deleting contacts isn't the solution.

When I really can't use those FCs at the moment, I just temporarily freeze my contact list, but it is such a hassle to do every time. I also tried to avoid the FC, but logcat is turned off and it doesn't help.

Isn't there a way to hide those notifications?

Comment: You can find some "first-aid" on our [force-close tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/force-close/info). Its [most frequented questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/force-close?sort=frequent) might also prove helpful. Having checked those, please come back, [edit] your question, and add what you've tried and where you're stuck – or answer your own question if you were able to solve the issue. Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts, by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your contacts backed up?

Try uninstalling Facebook if that is installed. If this does not fix your problem then try the following.

Settings>Applications>System Applications>Contacts Sync Adapter and press Clear Data, this error usually goes away. If this doesn't work, try clearing the data on Settings>Applications>System Applications>Contacts or Settings>Applications>System Applications>Contacts Storage.

Comment: well thanks for the answer, but i can't follow the path you suggest.When in settings>Applications i can only choose Downloaded,SD,and ALL. I chose All which includes system apps, but i can't find something similar with Contacts, Sync adapter or Contacts Storage. I can find Contacts storag in titanium backu, but this doesn't give the option to clear contacts sync adapter.